# Calcul on sql request wrong

Tags: mysql

I would know if you have an idea how make a correct sql request because the amount is wrong. The is request must calculate the sales amount and the number of order by country. All the result is displayed on a map by country.

In this case, the amount of the request below is = 18696, the value is completly wrong. This amount is sum of all status table.

But with the orders_status = 1 the amount must be 240

value of orders_total

```
orders_status 1 ==> 240
orders_status 3 ==> 456.0000
orders_status 3 ==> 18000.0000
```

request

```sql
    SELECT   COUNT(*) AS total,
             SUM(ot.value) AS amount,
             c.countries_iso_code_2 
    FROM     orders o,
             countries c, 
             orders_total ot
    WHERE    o.orders_status = 1 ===> 
    AND      o.billing_country = c.countries_name
    AND      ot.class = 'ST'
    GROUP BY o.billing_country
```

thank you

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : see below for image

Answer (score 0):

You’re not joining `orders_total` to the other tables in any way so you’ll get a Cartesian join here and rows will multiply. It’s easy to see if you remove grouping and summing.

Always use the standard JOIN syntax and these become easier to see:

```
select count(*) AS total,
       SUM(ot.value) as amount,
       c.countries_iso_code_2 
 from orders o
 join countries c on o.billing_country = c.countries_name
 join  orders_total ot on ??????
where o.orders_status = 1 ===> 
and ot.class = 'ST'
group by o.billing_country
```